# What is the synchronization source for the internal clock

Tags: sync, clock, date-and-time

Using a tool to compare the internal clock of my Android device to internet time servers, I noticed my device is 30 seconds wrong.

So that made me wondering what is the cause of this error. Where does Android gets it time from, so I can adjust or complain there:

I can think of the following sources:

- Provided by the cellular network provider.
- From GPS.
- From a NTP server on the local WIFI network.
- A global NTP server (hosted by Google)?

Comment: I've never understood why smartphone clocks are typically never synchronised by the OS with the time data received from GPS. I understand that there are 3rd party apps that can do this, it just seems a really obvious feature.

Answer (score 5):

When I go to my Date & time settings, there is option that says: Automatic - Use network-provided values. 
So, basing on this wording (also in other languages), I would say that automatic time is provided from your carrier.

There are apps, that can sync your clock with GPS satellites or NTP servers.

Comment: Note that there are carriers that doesn't provide time synchronization service, on those carriers you have to synchronize your clock manually

Comment: And without the device being rooted, those apps can only adjust the device's time when it's at least 30s off, unfortunately...

Comment: When I set a wrong time and switch back to automatic time, it's off by 0.2-0.3 seconds. Do you have anymore info on how this carrier-provided network time works? Like, does it literally go "Hey what's the time" -> "it's 12:43:30.2" or is there some back and forth to figure out the latency? Because 0.2-0.3s latency sounds fitting to me over 3g (HSDPA) abroad and would be a really stupid way of doing this.