# Is there NTP like time syncing for non rooted phone?

Tags: services, date-and-time

I need from time to time sync clock on android phone from internet. Traditional way on non mobile devices is to use NTP servers and daemon.
To run NTP daemon and automatically set time on android phone one requirement is to have a root access.
Is there really any similar solution for non-rooted phone?

Comment: It's unclear from your question whether you're aware, but by default your phone should sync with the time signal provided by your GSM network (as long as your network provides [NITZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NITZ) time info, most do. See also [Where time information is received from the network?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43386/) and [What is the synchronization source for the internal clock](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20933/)

Comment: It seems that it doesn't sync at least by default: I have 2-3 minutes shift beetween real and phone time.

Comment: Oh I had some wrong settings, now it works, I feel so dumb, but gratefull now. Thanks. However I see that non built-in solutions are not possible on non-rooted devices.

Comment: Please explain the settings you changed to fix it.  I have the same problem and have not yet figured out the solution.  :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, you really need root for this.

From [ClockSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.org.amip.ClockSync), Google themselves have mentioned this:

> Hi, it is by design that applications can not change the time. There are many subtle aspects of security that can rely on the current time, such as certificate expiration, license management, etc. We do not want to allow third party applications to globally disrupt the system in this way.

Comment: This is exactly the reason why I would like to have automatic time update by the way.. My tablet messes up time constantly and after that almost nothing works. They should add NTP to android core.